# Calculation of proximity between of one location to many other locations

Tags: c#, php, math, geolocation, proximity

I have a database with a list of latitude and longitude

```
-DeviceName
-Latitude
-Longitude
```

Given my current device's latitude and longitude, I want to get all devices within the database list in distance/proximity of X kilometres.

How do I calculate the proximity of my location vs other locations?

Comment: Are you thinking of making a SQL query?

Comment: yes, I would like to make an SQL query

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have a peep at this [amazing presentation](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL). it will tell you how to use (and for bonus points explains!) the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calcuate distances on the surface of the earth accounting for curviture and how to avoid some common mistakes in your database queries etc. His dataset is pretty much exactly what yours is - item, longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after the raw code, this should help you:

```
private static Double rad2deg(Double rad) {
    return (rad / Math.PI * 180.0);
}

private static Double deg2rad(Double deg) {
    return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

private const Double kEarthRadiusKms = 6376.5;

private static Double CalculateDistance(Double latitude1, Double longitude1, Double latitude2, Double longitude2) {
    double theta = longitude1 - longitude2;
    double dist = Math.Sin(deg2rad(latitude1)) * Math.Sin(deg2rad(latitude2)) + Math.Cos(deg2rad(latitude1)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(latitude2)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(theta));
    dist = Math.Acos(dist);
    dist = rad2deg(dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    dist = dist * 1.609344;
    return (dist);
}
```